# Why does Blender shut off when running a smoke simulation?

Tags: smoke-simulation

So I've decided to test run Blender. Usually I run Cinema 4D on my MS Studio here at work with no issues since it's never anything too demanding. I've found that if I run any kind of simulation Blender just shuts off. For example if I run even a simple smoke sim and preview in cycles, it's over..Blender just shuts off. Is this a hardware limitation? I never had issues with Cinema4D, Max, etc. Any help would be appreciated since I'd really like this option to work for us.

Comment: Hi. Can you explain what you mean by 'shuts off'? Blender instantly closes or does it become frozen? And when you say you "run even a simple smoke sim and preview in Cycles" do you mean you have baked (calculated/simmed) the simulation and then are trying to preview it, which is when it crashes, or that you are baking while trying to preview and it crashes? Any additional information you have can be added by using the [edit] button under the question.

Comment: Instant close is what I'm experiencing. I have no issues with baking the animation at all, since like I said I'm not really changing much other than putting in some wind and turbulence. Once the bake is done and I try to preview in cycles Blender just instantly closes. Like I said, I'm totally new to Blender so I'm just seeing what it can do. This is really the only issue I've had with it to be honest.

Comment: Ok, just trying to narrow down the actual issue. In your question you say the crash happens when you "run any kind of simulation" and also (?) when you "run even a simple smoke sim and preview in Cycles"? So is it when you change to rendered mode it crashes, when you bake the simulation or when you play back the simulation? Are you trying to play the smoke sim while previewing in Cycles or are you just trying to view a single frame?